# Wordpress - How to link to a couple of php scripts?

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

I have a page in my WordPress website that have a couple of links. Each link should refer to a PHP script file to do an action like downloading a file while staying in the same page without reloading the page.

I have created a folder called "scripts" in my WordPress theme to put all my PHP files inside it, and i have tested using direct links to those PHP scripts to be sure they work fine, like:

> http://my_wordpress_website.com/test_wordpress_project/wp-content/themes/theme-child/scripts/php_script1.php
>
> http://my_wordpress_website.com/test_wordpress_project/wp-content/themes/theme-child/scripts/php_script2.php

The links worked just fine when clicking them and the page wasn't reloaded of course. But since those links are invalid for WordPress and they expose my website, i am looking for a way to do the same behavior but with valid WordPress links, like:

> http://my_wordpress_website.com/php_script1
>
> http://my_wordpress_website.com/php_script2

**Is there anyway i could do this?**

Comment: What about moving the scripts folder you created to another location? or maybe using a plugin?

Comment: @bmcculley .. All PHP plugins that i have checked allow writing PHP code in normal WordPress pages. If i click the link it will redirect to that normal WordPress page which is not what i want. I want the PHP script to be executed while i am still in the same page of the link. That;s what happens when using PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using the [page-links-to WordPress plugin](http://txfx.net/wordpress-plugins/page-links-to/). It replaces my original PHP links with normal WordPress links.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to load PHP files without redirecting to them (and without using a plugin) I suggest you use an Ajax call.
Add this to a Javascript that loads on your page:

```
$('.doAjax').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://my_wordpress_website.com/my_ajax_handler.php'
    type: "POST",
    data: { action:'include_files_from_url', url:$(this).attr('href') },
    success : function (data) {
      //Actions upon success if needed.
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Make sure to fill the correct URL for your Ajax handler. The `action` data should be the name of the function that handles your Ajax request on the PHP side. 
The next step would be to add that PHP function to functions.php:

```
function include_files_from_url()
{
    //Optional data validation to prevent abuse.
    if ( !isset($_POST['url']) )
    {
      echo 'invalid file name.';
      die;
    }

    $allowedFiles = array(''); //Fill this with the file names you allow to be accessed.
    if ( !in_array($_POST['url'], $allowedFiles) ) return FALSE;
    //End of Optional data validation to prevent abuse.

    $result = @include_once('includes/' . $_POST['url']); //This function assumes your files are in an includes folder. Change as needed.
    if ($result) echo 'Successfully included ' . $_POST['url'];
    else echo 'Failed to include ' . $_POST['url'] . '. File was not found.';    
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_include_files_from_url', 'include_files_from_url' ); //To allow non-logged in user to use this call
add_action( 'wp_ajax_include_files_from_url', 'include_files_from_url' ); //To allow logged in user to use this call
```

Notice how this method gives you much more security options. First, the Javascript Ajax call does not specify your includes folder - that folder is only specified in the PHP file. On the PHP side we also check to see that a valid URL is asked for and that it is in your list of valid files to include. I encourage you to also add an array of valid ajax function names inside your ajax handler (so that any call to a function that you did not create will be refused).

Lastly, you can add URLs to be included to your HTML as such:

```
<a href="hello.php" class="doAjax">URL</a>
```